# What is the big O of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity, big-o

I think it's O(m*n) but someone said it's O(n). If you think it's O(n) could you provide an explanation?

```
def convert(self, s: str, numRows: int) -> str:
        if numRows == 1:
            return s
        res = ""
        for i in range(numRows):
            col = i
            while col < len(s):
                res += s[col]
                col_offset = 2 * (numRows - 1)
                col_next =  col + col_offset
                diag = col + 2 * (numRows - 1 - col % col_offset)
                if diag != col_next and diag != col and diag < len(s):
                    res += s[diag]
                col = col_next
        return res
```

Edit:
My solution:
Representing outer loop: `range(numRows)` by `m`. and for the inner loop I'm representing `len(s)` by `n`. For each iteration of `m` there is `n`. Therefore I think the time complexity is `O(mn)`. Is this correct?

Comment: Show your work as to what you have figured out so far.  Can you identify looping in the algorithm?

Comment: edited to show the work  @ErikEidt

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: This is buggy if len(s)<numrows*4-1 or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the inner loop increments `col` by `2 * (numRows - 1)` each time until its above `n`, its time complexity is `O(n/m)`. Doing this `m` times would give a total time complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: On the surface, I'd say this is right, but then it's really O(m * (len(s)/m)) and you are ignoring len(s) in your answer here.   len(s) is independent from m by the information given, so I think O(m*n) is still correct and O(n) is not.

Comment: @user10489 I'm using the definitions of `n = len(s)` and `m = numRows` from the question. The time depends only on `len(s)` because the `numRows` cancel out. As `numRows` increases, it increases the time for the outer loop and decreases the time for the inner one.

Comment: numrows does not increase, it is a static variable, nothing in this code changes it; so is col_offset, whose calculation could be lifted out of the loop.  I think it is still O(n*m) but I think n is = len(s)/m , which would make this O(len(s)) which I think is what you meant anyway.